# How to send newsletter in Magento With dynamic content?

Tags: magento, newsletter

I am Extremely New to Magento.

I have created newsletter template with dummy content. Now I need to replace dummy content with dynamic content. Basically I need to send mail with new featured products in site. What should be my next step? .

How to do this please help me .

Answer (score 1):

First you should create / override `Newsletter` module. I just suggest to send newsletter programmatic ally to customer

```
// This code returns all subscribers
$objCol=Mage::getResourceModel('newsletter/subscriber_collection')->load();
$collection = $objCol;
// Load the newsletter template model by $templateId

$tmplt=Mage::getModel('newsletter/template')->load($templateId);
$message=$tmplt->getTemplateText();
        foreach($collection->getItems() as $item) {

            $email = $item->getSubscriberEmail();
            $name = $item->getSubscriberFullName();

            try{
                    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                    $mail->setFrom($tmplt->getTemplateSenderEmail());
                    $mail->setBodyHtml($message);
                    $mail->addTo($email, 'recipient');
                    $mail->setSubject($tmplt->getTemplateSubject());
                    $mail->send();
                    echo "Newsletter sent to ".$email."<br>";

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }


        }

?>
```

May be help [Magento custom emails](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/)

Comment: Thanks for Replay.. I am Extremely new to magneto where should I need to put this code ???? how can I run this code ....

Comment: You should create a module then put the above code in an action.

Comment: @Anudeep. if your code is execute perfectly, than you can run from cronjob.